# Can I connect to host from docker container via 172.17.42.1?

Tags: docker

I've installed docker on several ubuntu servers.
Docker creates `docker0` all have the same IP (`172.17.42.1`).

```
$ ifconfig docker0
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2100 (2.1 KB)  TX bytes:547 (547.0 B)
```

Can I hardcode the IP address, so that I can contact the host machine from containers?
Will the `docker0` change to another IP in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the *bridge* that Docker creates (by default) for the containers that it runs.  This bridge works pretty much like an Ethernet switch on that machine - traffic coming onto the bridge from one interface is available to all other connected interfaces.

If you look further, you will see that every container also has a Virtual Ethernet device which is assigned an individual IP address. [Detailed Docker docs on networking.](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)

> Can I hardcode the IP address, so that I can contact the host machine from containers?

This doesn't follow - you can always contact the host machine from containers, irrespective of what IP addresses are assigned to the bridge and the containers.  Did you mean to ask something else?

> Will the `docker0` change to another IP in the future?

Yes, if that address space is occupied then Docker will attempt to find a different bit of private IP address space to use for the bridge and containers.